# Using the "CreateDocument" function in Mathematica without losing the formatting

Tags: string, formatting, wolfram-mathematica

I want to create a formatted document from a list of expressions. One of the expression in this list is the following:

```
text = Style["a\n\tb\n\t\tc", FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Monaco"]
```

And it gets formatted as planned:

[image]

But when I executed the following command to try to generate a document:

```
CreateDocument[{text}]
```

I got this:

[image]

Is there any way that we can keep the formatting of the string when using "CreateDocument" to generate document programmatically?

*Software platform: I am running Mathematica 8.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you pass just a string to `CreateDocument` (even if wrapped in `Style`), Mathematica creates a new document with the string inside a `TextCell`. This is why you see the literal string `"a\n\tb\n\t\tc"` displayed.

On the other hand, your formatted result is an `Output`. So you need to specify that the new document be created with a `TextCell` that is formatted with the style `"Output"`.

The following gives what you want:

```
CreateDocument[TextCell[text, "Output"]]
```

[image]

Comment: This time *you* beat *me*. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Refreshing for new questions gets faster now, the closer I get to tasting the silver badge :P

Comment: yoda, it looks like you're at 400, and should get the silver badge at any moment.  Congratulations!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks :) I'll probably get it an hr or so after the UTC day. At least, that's when I got my matlab silver